# Prove that $Q_{8}'=\{1,-1\}$. Is my proof correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-writing

Prove that Prove that $Q_{8}'=\{1,-1\}$.

My proof:

$Q_{8}'\neq \{1\}$, because $Q_{8}$ is not abelian. $|Q_{8}/\{-1,1\}|=4$. So  $Q_{8}/\{-1,1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ or  $Q_{8}/\{-1,1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then  $Q_{8}/\{-1,1\}$ is abelian.

Then I use a theorem:

Let $N \unlhd G  $. Then $G/N$ is abelian $\Leftrightarrow G'\subseteq N$.

Then $Q_{8}'\subseteq\{-1,1\}$. But we know that $Q_8'$ can't be $\{1\}$. Then $Q_{8}'=\{-1,1\}.$

Is it correct?

Comment: Assuming you already know that $\{1,-1\}\triangleleft Q_8$, this looks right.

Comment: What is the fastest way to show that it is a normal subgroup?

Comment: Well, since both $1$ and $-1$ commute with every element of $Q_8$, that should be easy.

Comment: Ahh. So from the definition we get that $\{-1,1\}Q_{8}=Q_{8}\{-1,1\}$. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Also observe that $\{1,-1\}=Z(Q_8)=Q_8'$. That eases the proof of normality of $\{1,-1\}$.